# Nested Relation Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

> class Airport extends Model{
>
> > public function flights(){
> >
> > > return $this->hasMany('App\Flights', 'flight_id', 'id');
> > > }
> > > }

> class FlightInfo extends Model{
>
> > public function status(){
> >
> > > return $this->hasMany('App\FlightStatus', 'flight_info_id', 'id');
> > > }
> > > }

> class FlightStatus extends Model{
>
> > public function flight_info(){
> >
> > > return $this->belongsTo(FlightInfo::class);
> > > }
> > > }

I'm trying to get all flights and its last status from one airport
example:

Airport::where('country_id', 10)->with(['flights.status' => function($q){$q->orderBy('last_update')->limit(1);}])

this give empty array for status collection

i've also tried

Airport::where('country_id', 10)->whereHas('flights.status', function ($q){$q->orderBy('last_update')->limit(1);})->with(['flights.status' => function($q){$q->orderBy('last_update')->limit(1);}])->get()

but same, empty array on status collection

I would like to retrieve this kind of result:

> [
> Airport_id: 2,
> flights:[
>
> > id: 10,
> > airport_id: 2,
> > status: [ status_id: 1]
> > ],
> > [ id: 15,
> > airport_id: 2,
> > status: [ status_id: 3]
> > ],

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it via SQL you should use `Joins`. You have three different tables, so you must join them together and then you can apply the where conditions to reduce the data.

See related documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#joins

---

If you have a small amount of data you could do it programmatically. (It's a dirty solution but may be enough for the given task).

You can get your Airport as a collection and the apply filter to remove unnecessary data.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-filter

Use eager loading in this case to reduce the amount of db queries:

See: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading